# SSLCaFileNotFound in Braintree payment gatway in php

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I am using PHP library of Braintree for Payment gateway when I am generating client token it's working fine on my local machine , but when I am using same code on server it's throw error.

```
"status": false,
"error": {
    "classname": "Braintree\\Exception\\SSLCaFileNotFound",
    "message": ""
}
```

----------Here is My Controller Where I genarating Token

```
        <?php
require_once "Braintree.php";

function testMerchantConfig()
{
    Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
    Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('XXXXXXX');
    Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('XXXXXXX');
    Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('XXXXXXX');
}
testMerchantConfig(); // With sendbox mode
  // integrationMerchantConfig(); // With live data

  date_default_timezone_set("UTC");

  class Btree
  {
    public static function getTokenClient()
    {
        return $clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate();
    }
}// class end
```

----------Here Is my Braintree.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Braintree PHP Library
 * Creates class_aliases for old class names replaced by PSR-4 Namespaces
 */

require_once(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'autoload.php');

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.2.0', '<')) {
    throw new Braintree_Exception('PHP version >= 7.2.0 required');
}

class Braintree {
    public static function requireDependencies() {
        $requiredExtensions = ['xmlwriter', 'openssl', 'dom', 'hash', 'curl'];
        foreach ($requiredExtensions AS $ext) {
            if (!extension_loaded($ext)) {
                throw new Braintree_Exception('The Braintree library requires the ' . $ext . ' extension.');
            }
        }
    }
}

Braintree::requireDependencies();
```

Comment: have you done a composer install on the other server? Do you have a CA file on the server?

Comment: pls give more details, which error do u receive? etc...

Comment: @Carlo1585 I am getting this error only

Comment: @delboy1978uk I am downloaded php library from Braintree official website

Comment: man I'm not php expert but if you leave the question as is it without share more information no one will help you, you need share the actual code you are running and the error for see where and why it's failing, you you share only this people don't know what u did

Comment: @Carlo1585 sure please see I added code here please take a look